# Raycast is acting strange and only working in some directions (unity 3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Basically, I want to shoot a raycast with slight random deviation. What is happening is that the Raycast is only shooting forward and not relative to the player (I have tried local position)
Trying to do other things gave me stranger results, here is my code which is placed on the firing point

```
   private void ShootRayCast()
{
    Ray rayDistance = new Ray(transform.position, BulletDirectionRandomness());
    RaycastHit hitInfo;
    Vector3 direction = BulletDirectionRandomness();

    if (Physics.Raycast(rayDistance, out hitInfo))
    {
        print(hitInfo.transform);
        print("hit");
        print(hitInfo.collider);

        if (hitInfo.collider.tag == "Wall")
        {
            // Instantiate(_bulletHole, hitInfo.point + new Vector3(0, 0.2f, -0.2f), Quaternion.LookRotation(hitInfo.normal + _bulletPosition));
        }
        Instantiate(_bulletHole, hitInfo.point + new Vector3(0, 0.2f, -0.2f), Quaternion.LookRotation(hitInfo.normal + _bulletPosition));
    }

    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, hitInfo.point);
}
```

and the random script:

```
 private Vector3 BulletDirectionRandomness()
{
    Vector3 direction = transform.forward;
    direction += new Vector3
    (
        Random.Range(_randomMinValue, _randoMaxValue),
        Random.Range(_randomMinValue, _randoMaxValue),
        Random.Range(_randomMinValue, _randoMaxValue)
    );
    direction.Normalize();
    return direction;
}
```

Comment: `DrawRay` expects a ray (position, direction) you are passing in two positions. Did you mean `DrawLine` instead?

Comment: I doesn't matter which gizmo I use the Raycast acts very strange. Sometimes it just only goes towards a specific direction for no reason

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right, you want to shoot a bullet forward from the camera.

```
    private void ShootRayCast()
    {
        //Cast a ray from camera position to camera forward vector
        var ray = new Ray(camera.transform.position, camera.transform.forward);
        //If ray hits nothing in range of 15 units return   
        if (!Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hitInfo, 15)) return; 

        print(hitInfo.transform);
        print("hit");
        print(hitInfo.collider);

        //Use CompareTag instead
        if (hitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Wall"))
        {
            // Instantiate(_bulletHole, hitInfo.point + new Vector3(0, 0.2f, -0.2f), Quaternion.LookRotation(hitInfo.normal + _bulletPosition));
        }

        Instantiate(_bulletHole, hitInfo.point + new Vector3(0, 0.2f, -0.2f),
            Quaternion.LookRotation(hitInfo.normal + _bulletPosition));
     }
```

Comment: Yes but I want the bullet to go slightly up or down randomly, And thanks for helping

Comment: And im shooting from a ‘fire point’ not a camera

Comment: I can't test my code rn.
But try to add 
`ray.direction += BulletDirectionRandomness();`
After Ray Creation